# Floated ::after interacting with block-level sibling

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having an interaction that I don't quite understand.  I'm building a progress bar (seriously, can we have the *entire* [standard](http://caniuse.com/progressmeter) implemented yet?) that displays info based off of data-* attributes, so I'm using :before and :after to display the labels.

I've got it in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WtrfL/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.wrap {
    width:500px;
    height:2em;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.wrap:before {
    content:"1";
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.wrap:after {
    content:"2";
    float:right;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.inner {
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border:1px solid #888;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm having this happen:

[image: Diagram showing an outer bar, an inner bar, a box with a 1 floating in the top left, and a box with a 2 beneath the outer bar floating on the right]

I'd expect the [2] to be inside of the main bar, not underneath it.

I'm seeing the same behavior in IE9 and Chrome 27 on Windows, so I'm pretty sure this is me misunderstanding the way these things are supposed to work, not a bug in a rendering engine.

So... what's up? Any ideas? I'm good with a hack, this is just a prototype for the present.

Comment: The `.wrap::before` pseudo-element appears just before `.inner` as a preceding sibling, and `.wrap::after`, as a following sibling. Since you're not floating `.inner`, `.wrap::after` has to shift beneath it before being floated to the right. The reason why `.wrap::before` is able to overlap `.inner` is because you're floating the pseudo-element, so `.inner` positions itself as if the pseudo-element wasn't there.

Comment: I was under the impression that inline-block elements ignore block elements when laying themselves out; is it more nuanced then that?  I know I've had instances where I placed an inline-block after a block and it hovered over the block.

Comment: Not exactly; in your case, you're applying floating to the pseudo-elements. When you float a box, it's always forced to display as a block. This is true even for pseudo-element boxes which are usually inlines (not inline blocks), and even if you try to force `display: inline-block`. Floats operate quite differently from inline blocks.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was working under the assumption that a float converted an element into an inline block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use floats on pseudo elements. I would position them absolute. Something like this:

```
.wrap {
    width:500px;
    height:2em;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap:before {
    content:"1";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.wrap:after {
    content:"2";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I tested it in your fiddle and looks fine! http://jsfiddle.net/WtrfL/1/